# Iterate files in website and loop to download files using curl in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have this website with files on it ending with the same word, such as ".csv". I am making a script to automate the download of the files ending with the same word and save it in a folder.

The instructions was to download the files using curl consecutively, and I know this would be possible by looping through the files and executing curl on each. Then, save the output on a folder.

I know the basics of batch script but I can't find clear reference or benchmark on how could this be done. I am new to curl, just an ethusiast and not really an IT person.

Can anyone give me ideas/instructions on how to do it or, if possible, show sample script for me to follow? Please leave comments on the script for me to better understand also. Thanks, much appreciated!

This is what Ive done so far:

```
 - > @echo off setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
       > 
       > set "MainURL=https://*****/****/***/"
       > 
       > for %%a in (%MainURL/*.properties%) do ( for /f "usebackq tokens=*
       > delims==" %%a in ("%%~Fx") do call :curldownload %%a
       > 
       > ) pause goto:eof
       > 
       > 
       > :curldownload 

       > set /a count=count+1 

         set STRING=%* curl -k -O -u username !STRING!| findstr /r [a-z]*.properties ? ? ?
       > 
       > :eof


       This is what I came up but not working properly..
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? We're not a code-writing or research service.

Comment: That is what I've done so far, sorry i forgot to put the code that I've tried. I updated my question, thank you

Comment: There is a ftp option in cmd if you just move all the files you want to somewhere then just download the folder with it. works great.